# Write table from R to Snowflake : table contains json element column

Tags: r, types, database-connection, snowflake-schema

I would like to write a table from R to snowflake using

```
 DBI::dbWriteTable(
  conn = con,
  name = DBI::SQL("db.schema.table"), 
  value = df
)
```

Table consists of 2 columns : `numeric`,`list/json`.

The problem is that 1 of the columns consists of jsons and it doesn't allow to write the table.

Data type in snowflake should be `variant`.

What modifications should I make, so I could write the table and at the end the data type is `variant`  in snowflake?

Data

[image]

An error message:

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) :
> RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'character'

And here the data example:

```
structure(list(id = c("1", "2"), json = list(structure("[\n  {\n    \"_id\": 1,\n    \"source_house_id\": \"68\",\n    \"source_room_id\": 33719,\n    \"substitute_rules\": [\n      {\n        \"destination_house_id\": \"388\",\n        \"destination_room_id\": 45231\n      },\n      {\n        \"destination_house_id\": \"478\",\n        \"destination_room_id\": 65216\n      },\n      {\n        \"destination_house_id\": \"503\",\n        \"destination_room_id\": 67624\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n]", class = "json"), 
    structure("[\n  {\n    \"_id\": 2,\n    \"source_house_id\": \"334\",\n    \"source_room_id\": 44329,\n    \"substitute_rules\": [\n      {\n        \"destination_house_id\": \"479\",\n        \"destination_room_id\": 65217\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n]", class = "json"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Please provide the data in usable format like `dput()`. Please visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please ask again adding the tag `snowflake-cloud-data-platform/`